# Overriding Magento Block

Tags: magento

I'm stuck. Been messing with this all day. To me this looks like it should work but It's not, and its not outputting any errors to magento error log.

What I tried to do was simply override the getPriceHtml() function in Catalog/Block/Product.php. The module is active from the 'Advanced' tab via the system configuration.

My config.xml in app/code/local/Brian/Pricefix/etc/config.xml:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Brian_Pricefix>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Brian_Pricefix>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product>Brian_Pricefix_Catalog_Block_Product</product>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

My Brian_Pricefix.xml in app/etc/modules:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Brian_Pricefix>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Brian_Pricefix>
    </modules>
</config>
```

My Product.php in app/code/local/Brian/Pricefix/Catalog/Block/Product.php

```
class Brian_Pricefix_Catalog_Block_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product
{
    public function getPriceHtml($product)
    {
        Mage::log("IM IN YOUR MODULEZ");
        $this->setTemplate('catalog/product/price_fix.phtml');
        $this->setProduct($product);
        return $this->toHtml();
    }

}
```

The new module isn't taking, its not logging anything or outputting price_fix.phtml

Any suggestions? I've done a few hours or research and this appears to be the right way to extend a block, so i'm not sure whats going on. The lack of error output is frustrating.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product` is not used anywhere.
catalog.xml contains mainly `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View` or `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` calls.
You config looks fine.
 Try overriding another block.
Can you precise the page you are testing on?

Comment: Mage_Catalog_Block_Product is the class name of the original file I'm trying to extend -- which is app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product.php

Comment: I know that. I wanted to say that this block is not used on frontend. How can you be sure that it's called?

Comment: Ah its used on product page template files and specifically -- getPriceHtml() is used in app/design/frontend/base/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

Comment: ok. what magento version are you using?
I see that in `base/template/catalog/product/list.phtml ` is used `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List`. `Product_List` extends `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract`. So from my Magento CE 1.6.2 looks like `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product` is not used in list.
Try `Mage::log(get_class($this))` in `template/catalog/product/list.phtml ` and see what it returns.

Comment: Ok, yes I see the same thing you do. I guess i'm not exactly seeing how they are getting access to getPriceHtml in Mage_Catalog_Block_Product ... I should just extend _List and I'm all set ?

Comment: Ah nevermind, now I see that method in the Abstract class. I guess the other one is left over from a previous version

Comment: yep, *_List is the one you need

Comment: Hi I am also facing this issue on product view page, I want to use my own phtml file but this is not coming .